# Any query in code to local postgress on windows return ECONNREFUSED (111)

Tags: postgresql, go

Writing GO code on windows to query local postgress. I get no errors when connecting to the db, but when I run any query, I get os.syscallError  ECONNREFUSED (111). Any idea what is wrong? Thanks!

All connection arguments are ok as I do not get error on sql.open command. I also double checked them.
I can see all information of tables in pgAdmin.
Of course I can connect with psql and the server is running

I'm using "github.com/lib/pq" driver

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    host := "localhost"
    port := 5432
    user := "postgres"
    password := "postgres"
    dbname := "testdb"

    // Connect to the database
    connStr := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // defer db.Close() // Ping the database to check connection //db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Duration(5 * time.Second))
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

```
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin>psql -U postgres -d testdb -h localhost -p 5432
Password for user postgres:
psql (15.5)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

testdb=#
```

running on local machine. no docker

Comment: [`sql.Open`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open) may (driver dependent) not actually connect to the database (use [`Ping`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Ping) if you want to verify a connection can be made). It's going to be difficult to help further [without more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (e.g. your code, info on the database configuration etc).

Comment: ECONNREFUSED suggests the port isn't open.  What `psql` command is working for you?  Are you sure it uses `localhost` and not `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments (edit the question instead). I expected `Ping` would fail (the point is that you are not connecting successfully at all). You will need to provide further information re the database configuration.

Comment: the code is in the question. using localhost as shown above. ping returns error.  can connect with psql and run queries.

Comment: Please show us the `psql` command you are using to connect (as requested by @erik258 above). Can you please also confirm how this is all running (i.e. is everything running directly on the host, or are you using something like Docker).

Comment: @Brits I have updated the question with the psql command. running on local machine no docker

Comment: OK - the above code runs fine on my machine (with amended user/password etc). Please try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`; it's probably also worth checking the Postgres log. Sorry - running out of ideas as everything looks fine with the code; might be worth trying [jackc/pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) just in case (I'd recommend that over `lib/pq` now anyway).

Comment: I see a windows prompt.  I suspect something windowsy; it's a quirky OS.  Don't know what that would be